# Can you develop iOS apps that will generate revenue using XCode from the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode

I noticed in the [Apple Media Services Terms and Conditions](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/) it states:

> You may use the Services and Content only for personal, noncommercial purposes (except as set forth in the App Store Content section below).

I looked at the App Store Content section and didn't find anything relevant to my question. Based on the statement excerpted above, it sounds like I cannot generate revenue from any iOS apps that I develop using XCode from the App Store (since XCode would fall under an Apple Media Service). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Why do you think Xcode is a media service? Also, please add links to any source/document you refer to.

Comment: I was under the assumption that since XCode is in the App Store it fell under this agreement. Noted about adding links. Will do that in the future.

Comment: You can edit posts to add details if necessary. Also, please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is about https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html. From the first paragraph there:

> This Agreement governs your use of Apple’s Services (“Services” – e.g., and where available, App Store, Apple Arcade, Apple Books, Apple Fitness+, Apple Music, Apple News, Apple News+, Apple One, Apple Podcasts, Apple Podcast Subscriptions, Apple TV, Apple TV+, Apple TV Channels, Game Center, iTunes), through which you can buy, get, license, rent or subscribe to content, Apps (as defined below), and other in-app services (collectively, “Content”).

So these T&C apply to the use of media/content services provided by Apple (movies, music etc), not to software development.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your headline question:

Yes, you can definitely develop iOS apps using Xcode that will generate revenue for you from the App Store!

However, in order to be able to do so, you must first enroll in the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/). It has a separate set of terms and conditions, and they will allow you to generate revenue from sales in the App Store. Note that being enrolled in the program costs $99 per year.